# How do I display a self-made bitmap at native resolution in iOS8

Tags: ios

I'm developing a universal app for iOS which will dynamically generate it's own full-screen bitmaps (a pointer to 32-bit pixel data in a byte buffer). It reacts to touch events and needs to do the drawing in a responsive way as the user touches (e.g. zooms/pans). At the start of my app, I can see that the display is scaled by 2x on my retina iPad and iPod Touch. My code currently creates and displays bitmaps correctly, but at 1/2 the native resolution of the display. I can see the native resolution using the nativeBounds of the view, but I would like to create and display my bitmaps at native resolution without any scaling. I tried changing the transform scale in the drawRect() method, but it didn't work correctly. Below is my drawRect code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UInt32 * pixels;
    pixels = (UInt32 *)[TheFile thePointer];
    NSUInteger width = [TheFile iScreenWidth];
    NSUInteger height = [TheFile iScreenHeight];
    NSUInteger borderX = [TheFile iBorderX];
    NSUInteger borderY = [TheFile iBorderY];
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef gtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width-borderX*2, height-borderY*2, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGImageRef myimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gtx);

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(gtx, kCGInterpolationNone); // does this speed it up?

    // Create a rect to display
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(borderX, borderY, width - borderX*2, height - borderY * 2);

    // Need to repaint the background that would show through (black)
    if (borderX != 0 || borderY != 0)
    {
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        UIRectFill(rect);
    }

    // Transform image (flip right side up)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, myimage); //image.CGImage);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(gtx);
    CGImageRelease(myimage);

} /* drawRect() */
```

***Edit:*** The answer below fixes both the performance issue by using a UIImageView, and the scaling issue by setting the proper display scale in the initialization of the UIImage. When the UIImage scale matches the display scale, then it will display bitmaps at 1:1 with the native resolution of the device.

Comment: what do you mean a pointer? Is it an `CGImageRef`? Do you read image data from disk and use it as background? If that's the case, there is no need to draw it. Just use an `UIImageView` to render it. Only draw image when you need to create it on the fly.

Comment: A pointer to a byte array that I allocate and generate

Comment: So you will modify the pixel array frequently and for every time, you must refresh the view ? The size of pixel array should be `scale*widthInPoint * scale*heightInPoint`, in retina display device, scale is 2.0, non-retina is 1.0, in iPhone6 plus, it is 3.0.

Comment: @KudoCC - Yes, I have a byte array that I allocate at program init to the size of the display and I redraw the pixels myself (with ASM code). I need the pixels to be transferred to the display 1:1 as quickly as possible. I know how big to allocate it (native res). What I need to know is how to draw it 1:1 on the display surface quickly.

Comment: Despite of the speed of drawing, the size of pixel array should be different for different display like I mentioned above. In iOS, one point is one*scale pixel and you can't suppose the scale is two.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope that can help you.

Comment: @KudoCC - I understand the situation with different display resolutions/scales. I can create my bitmap at native resolution. I need to be able to quickly draw it 1:1 on the display. I guess I'm not explaining myself well because both you and wcd seem to be focused on the wrong issue.

Comment: Have you tried the code I just edited? When using `UIImageView` to render an image, the image data is uploaded to GPU directly which would be much faster. The problem of your code snippet is that after rendered bitmap data, you already get the image, and then you **draw** it which takes 70ms. This is a CPU-bound operation, thus it's slow.

Comment: The UIImageView code allows me to update the bitmap in 2ms on an iPod touch. The problem remains that the scale is wrong. The native resolution of the iPod display is 640 x 1136. I create a bitmap of that size and need to display it 1:1 on the display, but right now I see the upper left corner of my bitmap.

Comment: use `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]` instead of `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]` fix the scaling problem. I'll edit my answer. Sorry for the late.

Comment: I already tried that before - no effect. In order to get a correct answer, please stop guessing and use an actual bitmap that you can see if it displays correctly.

Comment: hmm..that's strange. I tested in my device this time. It seems ok on my device.... The resolution is correct. I don't know why it doesn't work on your device.

Comment: It's not a device issue. I tested it on a iPad mini retina and 5th generation iPod touch. I can clearly see that the bitmap is not displayed at native resolution. How are you confirming that yours is working?

Comment: huh...I only have a iPhone 4. I set a breakpoint and checked the logical size and scale of the output image. It's correct. I created a bitmap context of which the size is 620 x 480 pixels. It renders on my iPhone 4 as 310 x 240 points. I took a screenshot. I don't know, it looks the size is 310 x 240 points to me.

Comment: besides the approach you used to create an image, you can also create an image directly with function `CGImageCreate`. Check the API doc of this function if you are interested. That way you don't need an extra graphic context. Since you are manipulating bitmap and creating images from that bitmap, not drawing stuff, I think creating image directly is more straightforward in your case. A graphic context is usually used when drawing stuff with techniques like `Core Graphics` or `UI Graphics` both of which are CPU-bound operation.

Comment: also if you would like to use an UIView or just a stand-alone `CALayer` to render images, you can set contents of layer directly. The performance should be similar to UIImageView approach. Although UIView is a thin wrapper around CALayer and UIImageView is extremely optimized, it is CALayer that actually renders stuff behind the scene. Using CALayer to render static images may have a little performance benefit. But if the background needs to handle touch events, then use a background view instead of an extra UIImageView to render images can flatten view hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of your code is that after the result image is created, the code draws the image into current graphic context configured for `drawRect:`. It's CPU that draws the image. That's why it takes 70ms. Rendering the image with an `UIImageView` or set it as the contents of a layer is not handled by CPU, in this way, it's handled by GPU. GPU is good at things like this, so it's much faster in this case. Since `drawRect:` causes `Core Animation` to create a backing bitmap which is useless in this case, you should create the image without `drawRect:`:

```
- (UIImage *)drawBackground {
    UIImage *output;
    UInt32 * pixels;
    pixels = (UInt32 *)[TheFile thePointer];
    NSUInteger borderX = [TheFile iBorderX];
    NSUInteger borderY = [TheFile iBorderY];
    NSUInteger width = [TheFile iScreenWidth] - 2 * borderX;
    NSUInteger height = [TheFile iScreenHeight] - 2 * borderY;
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    // create bitmap graphic context
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef gtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, 
                                             width, 
                                             height,
                                             bitsPerComponent,
                                             bytesPerRow, 
                                             colorSpace, 
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | 
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    // create image
    CGImageRef myimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gtx);
    output = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myimage 
                                 scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale 
                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    // clean up
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(gtx);
    CGImageRelease(myimage);

    return output;
}
```

when user triggers an event, suppose you use a gesture recognizer:

```
- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    UIImage *background = [self drawBackground];

    // when background view is an UIImageView
    self.backgroundView.image = background;
    // self.backgroundView should have already set up in viewDidLoad
    // based on your code snippet, you may need to configure background color
    // self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    // do other configuration if needed...

    // when background view is an UIView or subclass of UIView
    self.backgroundView.layer.contents = (id)background.CGImage;
    // not like UIImageView, the size of background view must exactly equals 
    // to the size of background image. Otherwise the image will be scaled.
}
```

---

I wrote this function in a test project:

```
static UIImage *drawBackground() {
    // allocate bitmap buffer
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    NSUInteger borderWidth = 1 * 2; // width of border is 1 pixel
    NSUInteger width = scale * CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds) - borderWidth;
    NSUInteger height = scale * CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds) - borderWidth;
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;

    // test resolution begin
    // tested on a iPhone 4 (320 x 480 points, 640 x 960 pixels), iOS 7.1
    // the image is rendered by an UIImageView which covers whole screen.
    // the content mode of UIImageView is center, which doesn't cause scaling.
    width = scale * 310; 
    height = scale * 240;
    // test resolution end

    UInt32 *pixels = malloc((size_t)(width * height * bytesPerPixel));

    // manipulate bitmap buffer
    NSUInteger count = width * height;
    unsigned char *byte = (unsigned char *)pixels;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1) {
        byte[0] = 100;
        byte = byte + 1;
        byte[0] = 100;
        byte = byte + 1;
        byte[0] = 0;
        byte = byte + 2;
    }

    // create bitmap grahpic context
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef gtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels,
                                             width,
                                             height,
                                             bitsPerComponent,
                                             bytesPerRow,
                                             colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    // create image
    CGImageRef myimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gtx);
    UIImage *output = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myimage 
                                          scale:scale 
                                    orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    // clean up
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(gtx);
    CGImageRelease(myimage);
    free(pixels);

    return output;
}
```

I tested it on a iPhone 4 device. Seems ok to me. This is the screenshot:
[image: image created from bitmap]

Comment: Can you please modify your answer to fit my question? My app reacts to user input and needs to redraw the entire screen after touch events. I have a pointer to the pixel data that I generate quickly and I need to display it fullscreen as quickly as possible. Background processing is not needed nor useful in this case. Where will 'drawBackground' get called from? What's the correct way to draw the entire UIView with my bitmap?

Comment: well that can be called anywhere since it just creates an image. For example, user triggered an event, in event handling method, you draw an image and use this image to update the entire screen. For now, I only know you want to draw an image but not sure how you would use this image.

Comment: That's what I'm asking - how do I use the image to redraw the entire screen if not inside the drawRect method?

Comment: that's very easy. You can do stuff like this: `backGroundView.layer.contents = (id)background.CGImage` if the background view is a general `UIView`. Or you can use an `UIImageView` as the background view and just `background.image = background`. This will update screen.

Comment: You should know that if you are drawing in main thread, the main thread will be blocked until the drawing finishes. During drawing your whole app will be frozen which probably makes users unhappy... @BitBank

Comment: This kind of operation isn't a problem on Android devices. My code takes 2-5ms to update the bitmap data and then Android takes 5-10ms to draw it on the screen and the user doesn't feel the delay. There must be a more efficient way on iOS to simply draw a fullscreen bitmap from a pointer.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe that's because you used `drawRect:`. When `Core Animation` detected you defined this method even though it's a empty method does nothing, it will allocate a backing bitmap and cache the result to speed up animation later. This is expensive and useless in most cases. You can try my approach and profile again. I think performance shouldn't be that bad. @BitBank

Comment: I tried the UIImageView idea and it's definitely faster and does work. Now the only remaining problem is the scale is still wrong. If I create a UIImage the size of the native display resolution, it only displays 1/4 of the bitmap in the UIImageView. I don't want the UIImageView to scale down my bitmap, I want to display it 1:1 on the screen. If you can solve this issue, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I'm already doing what you just edited and it doesn't display the bitmap at native resolution. If I set the contentmode of the UIImageView to UIViewContentModeTopLeft to disable scaling, it's drawing it scaled *2 so that I only see the upper 1/4 of my image.